# parsing JSON embedded structure

Tags: json

My JSON response comes like below:

```
"channels": {
            "BB0AC397-78AA-41C9-818A-A52A6BC81E9B": {

                "id": "BB0AC397-78AA-41C9-818A-A52A6BC81E9B",
                "name": "MyVABotChannel",
            },
            "94612845-7868-4B1C-8E58-7BD88869B197": {

                "id": "94612845-7868-4B1C-8E58-7BD88869B197",
                "name": "System_Bot_Test",


            }
```

my requirement is to extract the id of the structure where name is MyVABotChannel.  the id are not fixed and random when they will come from server. so how do i find the id corresponding to the specific name.

Comment: In what language? What JSON library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming javascript

This snippet assumes multiple entries with "MyVABotChannel"

```
// response = JSON
var values = Object.values(response.channels);
var botChannels = values.filter(channel => channel.name === "MyVABotChannel");
```

This snippet assumes one entry with "MyVABotChannel"

```
// response = JSON
var values = Object.values(response.channels);
var botChannels = values.find(channel => channel.name === "MyVABotChannel");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in JavaScript or any library that exposes a JSON DOM, then like so:

```
var channels = ...

var key = Object
    .getKeys( channels )
    .find( e => chanels[e].name == "MyVABotChannel" );

if( key == null ) {
    console.log("Couldn't find element.");
    return;
}

var result = channels[key].id;
console.log( result );
```